# How to output these values in a list from PHP - array_keys()?

Tags: php, html, arrays, database

I'm having trouble trying to output array values into separate list items like so:

- 1993 Mercedes Benze Own
- 2006 Honda Fit Lease

. Here's the output by `print_r($array)`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [{"Year":"1993","Make":"Mercedes","Model":"Benz","Lease / Own":"Own"},{"Year":"2016","Make":"Honda","Model":"Fit","Lease / Own":"Lease"}]
)
```

However, the format is tricky for me and I'm not exactly sure where I should go from here in order to output the values when they are laid out like this.

I know it has to do with `array_keys()`, but I'm lost as to where to go from here since the following gives me nothing:

```
print_r(array_keys($array));
```

Any clues to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Inside your index 0 is a json type. So `$val = json_decode($yourData[0], true);` then use `array_keys`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing you've shown has anything to do with `array_keys()`. First thing is decode the 0 index of your array that is JSON:

```
$result = json_decode($array[0], true);
```

Then loop through it:

```
foreach($result as $value) {
    echo "{$value['Year']} {$value['Make']} {$value['Model']} {$value['Lease / Own']}<br>\n";
}
```

If you need the keys (Year, Make, Model, Lease / Own) as column headings or whatever then you can use array keys on the first row of the result:

```
foreach(array_keys($result[0]) as $heading) {
    echo "$heading<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<ol>";
foreach ($array as $x) {
    $x = json_decode($x);
    $x = (array) $x;
    foreach($x as $y) {
        $data       = ( array ) $y;
        $year       = $data['Year'];
        $make       = $data['Make'];
        $leaseOwn   = $data['Lease / Own'];

        echo ("<li>{$year} {$make} {$leaseOwn}</li>"); 
    }
}
echo "</ol>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo '<ul>';
for ($i=0; $i <count($array[0]); $i++) {
    echo '<li>' . $array[0][$i]->year . ' ' . $array[0][$i]->make . ' ' . $array[0][$i]->model . ' ' . $array[0][$i]->{"Lease / Own"} . '</li>';
 }
echo '</ul>';
```